# Background change on landscape mode

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, background

I have a background image.. it changes resolution when changing the screen to landscape mode. I want just to set another background image for the landscaped version of the page. any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To **easily** do that with **xml only**:
Put another folder in your res directory: **layout-land**
Replicate your main xml file, but this time change your image background reference.

And that's it, **no need** to hassle with code.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the Required Orientation

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

switch (rotation) {
case Surface.ROTATION_0:
    // Protrait
    break;
case Surface.ROTATION_90:
    // LandScape
    break;
case Surface.ROTATION_180:
    // Reverse Protrait
    break;
case Surface.ROTATION_270:
    // Reverse LandScape
    break;
}
```